# Print is Returning Extra Parenthesis No Matter What I Do

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am trying to code a function for practice that will make a grid.

The current code simply makes a 2x2 fancy looking grid:

```
First = [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]
Second = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15]

x = 0

while True:
    if x in First:
        print '+', '-' * 4, '+', '-' * 4, '+', '-' * 4, '+', '-' * 4, '+'
        x += 1

    elif x in Second:
        print '|', ' ' * 4, '|', ' ' * 4, '|', ' ' * 4, '|', ' ' * 4, '|'
        x += 1

    else:
        break
```

That looks like:

```
+ - - - - + - - - - +
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
+ - - - - + - - - - +
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
+ - - - - + - - - - +
```

I am trying to expand this code to make make a function that takes arguments of length and width and makes a grid of that size.

```
def grid_maker(length, height):
```

The issue I am having is that I can not for the life of me get it to correctly repeat the pattern multiple times.

If I do something like:

```
bob = '+', '-' * 4
print bob + bob
```

or

```
print bob * length
```

It has parenthesis at the start and end, as if it's making a list with each entry being bob.

Is there a way that I can repeat this pattern an x amount of times and have it print exactly as is without extra commas or parenthesis being added in?

EDIT: Using Python2.7

Answer (score 3):

This line:

> ```
> bob = '+', '-' * 4
> ```

creates a tuple.

```
bob = '+' + '-' * 4
```

Comment: That makes the grid look slightly more compact, but works! How come the commas screw it over when printing multiple times, but when I print it just once like my original code it works? Is the original code actually just printing lists separated by spaces?

Comment: `print` takes comma-separated arguments.  A comma on the RHS of an assignment creates a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
bob = '+', '-' * 4
```

is a tuple it is equivelent to

```
bob = ('+', '----')
```

I think you want

```
bob = '+' + '-'*4
```